# Google web font Source Sans Pro displayed in italic in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts

I have a website which displays wrongly in Chrome. To eliminate all factors I used Googles example:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Serif+Pro|Source+Sans+Pro">
<style>
  body {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size: 48px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div>Making the Web Beautiful in Source Sans Pro!</div>
  <div style="font-family: 'Source Serif Pro', sans-serif">Making the Web Beautiful in Source Serif Pro!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I can not get sans to display normally (Chrome v53.0.2785.116 m):
[image]

Comment: Looks fine for me, does a hard refresh (Cmd/Ctrl + Shift + R) help? (i.e. a refresh with no caching). Are there any errors in the console or network tab of your browser's developer tools?

Comment: No, no errors, same result in private tab. Restartet Chrome. Cleared Cache, tried different settings hardware acceleration. Fonts in default setting. Opera has the same issue. IE and Firefox fine.

Answer (score 1):

Found it, seems to me like an error in the font:

After analyzing Googles own Website I found out that one has to use:

```
 font-family: 'Source Sans Pro rev=1', sans-serif;
```